# Почему Django не выводит изображение через папку static?

Tags: python, html, django, изображения, static

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "main/static"
]
```

в html шаблоне:

```
{% load static %} <img src="{% static 'acc/media/logotw.png' %}">
```

Две папки static, одна в приложении main, другая в acc, html шаблон из acc.
На сайте изображение не появляется, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

при обращении к файлу

```
{% load static %} <img src="{% static 'acc/media/logotw.png' %}">
```

если ты хочешь, чтобы статический файл был расположен в приложении acc, то необходимо, чтобы

1. приложение было добавлено в файле settings в INSTALLED_APPS
2. Файл должен располагаться по адресу`/acc/static/acc/media/logotw.png` (acc в пути будет встречаться дважды)